# How to create classes with template in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a template class, but some erros has ocurred when i define the methods in the array.cpp file

**here are the source code files**(i can't post more than 1 hiperlink >.<):

main.cpp: pastebin.com/DxLFDhnc

array.hpp: pastebin.com/MmCAj3Ci

array.cpp: pastebin.com/32czzPBc

**errors**:

main.cpp undefined reference to `Array::Array(unsigned int)'

main.cpp undefined reference to `Array::operator[](unsigned int)'

main.cpp undefined reference to `Array::operator[](unsigned int)'

main.cpp undefined reference to `Array::operator[](unsigned int)'

main.cpp undefined reference to `Array::length()'

main.cpp undefined reference to `Array::operator[](unsigned int)'

main.cpp undefined reference to `Array::~Array()'

main.cpp undefined reference to `Array::~Array()'

=== Build finished: 8 errors ===

Comment: Can you put your source code files in the question itself please? If they're very long, please create a shorter example first.

Comment: what's up with the downvote? we were all beginners once...

Comment: @salami - Yes.  And when I was a beginner I learned really quick to ask clear and concise questions after doing my own research.  I realize that's more or less an, "I walked 20 miles in the snow," story to many these days, but it's really a better way to learn and get good.

Answer (score 2):

This should answer your question:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted some code that's giving the error. But from the error messages you're getting, I would say you're class template isn't fully defined in the source unit that instantiates an instance of it. Look at nanothief's link for more info.